# How can I parse a HTML page with HtmlAgilityPack, where the nodes I need are only loaded with jQuery if the user is connected with a web browser?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, uwp

I am doing my final school project which involves making a touch-based information screen for the students. One of the features will be showing the lunch menu on the main page of the application (Universal Windows).

But I have run into a problem, there is no public API (and my school will not allow me to use the private one) to retrieve the lunch menu. So I figured I would parse the HTML page and get the menu. But the HTML page does not populate the nodes, where the food is listed, until you connect to the page with a web browser. I think the page is using jQuery to do this, and I can not find a solution at all on how to do this with HtmlAgilityPack.

How can I parse a HTML page with HtmlAgilityPack, where the nodes I need are only loaded with jQuery if the user is connected with a web browser?

Link to the HTML page: [clicky](https://mpi.mashie.eu/public/menu/motala+kommun/af77367d)

This is the HTML part I want to parse, as you can see the `span` is empty, and only populates when I connect with a web browser:

```
<div class="clearpadding col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5" style="text-align: center">
    <span class="webmenu-weekday webmenu-today">
    </span>
</div>
```

And this is my C# code:

```
const string urlToFetchFrom = @"https://mpi.mashie.eu/public/menu/motala+kommun/af77367d";
var webClient = new HtmlWeb();

 HtmlDocument document = await webClient.LoadFromWebAsync(urlToFetchFrom);
 HtmlNode root = document.DocumentNode;
 var nodes = root.Descendants().Where(n => n.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Equals("webmenu-weekday webmenu-today"));
```

Comment: You can try to read the data in `weekData` object and parse that json..

Comment: @Eser How did I not see that json at the bottom... I guess I was to busy looking into the .js files... I will try that! Thanks!